# How do I distinguish wanting something to happen vs predicting it will happen?

Tags: word-choice, differences, slang, informal-writing

This question comes from arises from cases of [shipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipping_(fandom)) as in (romantic) relationship - ping; [The Psychology of Shipping](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/psychology-tomorrow/201807/the-psychology-shipping) and [The Psychology of Shipping](https://frogkun.com/2013/10/05/the-psychology-of-shipping).

What happened was that I saw this forum where 1 person, person X, thought characters A and B would end up in a relationship and then another person, person Y, who didn't think so, misinterpreted person X as saying 'Even though I don't have basis to think A and B will end up in a relationship, I like the idea' and then criticised person X for the *desire* not the *prediction*.

My goal is to ask for a term to distinguish the ff 2 cases of shipping:

1. **Prediction**: I think characters A and B will end up in a relationship (eg HIMYM / HIMYF; Definitely, Maybe; The Quintessential Quintuplets), but I don't necessarily have any opinion about this relationship (eg whether it is better than another eg a possible relationship between characters A and C).
2. **Wanting**: I would like characters A and B to be in a relationship. I think they will be good together. I think that this relationship would be better than a possible relationship between characters A and C.

Usually when people say they 'ship' A and B, it's more of type 2. **How would someone distinguish themselves as a Case 1 shipper aside from linking to this Stack Exchange post?**

But then I realised I can actually generalise this question to asking how to distinguish thinking something will happen vs wanting something to happen. **How do I do this in general?**

**Guess**: 1 idea I had in mind is using the terms [positive vs normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_statement#Positive_statements_and_normative_statements) statements. Positive is about 'what is', and normative is about 'what should be'. For example in economics (whence [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_economics) vs [normative economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative_economics)), 1 might say a stock price is this, but then another might say said stock is undervalued and should be priced much higher. **Can positive extend to 'what I think will be'?**

If so, then I guess for the case of the shipping I'll just say positive shipper vs normative shipper.

Related:

I actually did sort of ask this before in English SE and then in Law SE when I asked the [opposite of 'argumentative'](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-the-opposite-of-argumentative/54809#54809) and then I got 'factual'. I think 'factual' has a similar problem to 'positive' in that they're both talking about 'what is' but not necessarily 'what I think will be'.

Comment: The sense/s of the verb you mention haven't made it into many reputable dictionaries so far. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ship) adds a further, seemingly causative, subsense: _to promote or ... a romantic relationship between_. The subsenses haven't settled down to an agreed default usage yet. The word is inherently ambiguous, multiply.

Comment: Maybe they say, “I’m really more of a prognosticatorial shipper.”

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmmmm...ah I have an idea. How about never mind the shipping and just distinguish between thinking something will happen vs wanting something to happen?

Comment: @Jim Thanks. Could be. Actually, I have an idea. How about never mind the shipping and just distinguish between thinking something will happen vs wanting something to happen?

Comment: This is a sensible question to ask, but it may not be capable of a definite answer, as the term is fairly new and appears only in highly informal contexts, so the boundaries of its meaning may still be in a state of flux. Nevertheless, it is possible that somebody better versed in the relevant slang will be able to post a definite answer, so the question should remain open.

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks. How about never mind the shipping and just distinguish between thinking something will happen vs wanting something to happen? Oh wait...is this like [factual vs argumentative](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-the-opposite-of-argumentative) perhaps? Or like [positive vs normative](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-the-opposite-of-argumentative/54809#54809) ?

Comment: @BCLC, several of your comments on this page seem to indicate that you want to ask some new question, different from this one. If so, and if it is within the scope of this site, you should post it on a separate page.

Comment: @jsw29 I was asking about reformulating this question: Do you think it's better if I just omit the shipping or at least reduce it to context and and instead ask how to distinguish wanting something to happen vs thinking something will happen?

Comment: @BCLC, this is an entirely different question, so it should have been asked separately, rather than by way of editing the one about *shipping*, among other reasons, because doing it by editing has rendered the existing answer out of place.

Comment: It is rather unclear what the new question is really seeking. If one needs to make it make it clear whether something is a prediction or an expression of a want, one can always do so by using the words *predict* and *want* themselves. Why do you think you need some other words to accomplish the same result?

Comment: The question is essentially about believing something will happen or hoping something will happen. It could have been posed concisely instead of at such length with so much extraneous detail,  but is nevertheless amenable to an answer. Reopen.

Comment: For the record, I need to make it clear that my first comment above, about keeping the question open, and my vote to reopen, were directed at the original question, not the **entirely new** question that now stands in its place.

Answer (score 0):

You should have given us at least one dictionary definition!

Dictionary.com:

> take an interest in or hope for a romantic relationship between (fictional characters or famous people), whether or not the romance actually exists: I’m shipping for those guys—they would make a great couple!

This seems to be compatible with Urban Dictionary and your #2.

Frankly your best bet might be to ask around among people familiar with this modern usage of the word.

Comment: Hmmmm...ah I have an idea. How about never mind the shipping and just distinguish between thinking something will happen vs wanting something to happen?

Comment: It is not clear that the quoted definition provides a definite answer to the question, as 'take an interest' is compatible with both 1. and 2.

Comment: @jsw29 - I was going by the example sentence in the dictionary entry, and by Urban Dictionary -- but otherwise I have never heard or seen "ship" used in this sense.

Comment: aparente001 and @jsw29 I edited the question.

Comment: You might be better off starting over from scratch with a brand new question -- but how's this?  I predict X, but I have no [personal] preference [stake in the game, horse in the race, etc.].